# Script to keep the latest 5 files and rest will be moved to other destination

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, solaris, ksh

Source path:

`/var/log/`

Here I have 4 folders named `ad1nrld,ad2nrld,icp1rmnrl,icp2rmnrl`

I can move all the files to the other destination named `/home/spsy/logs_bkp`. But I want to keep latest 5 files in each folders (ad1nrld,ad2nrld,icp1rmnrl,icp2rmnrl) of this `/var/log` path and rest will be moved to `/home/spsy/logs_bkp` path.

At source path,
`/var/log/ad1nrld` - Only latest 5 files will be present and rest will be moved to `/home/spsy/logs_bkp/ad1nrld` path

I have tried the below code for moving the files and they are successfully moved. But I am unable to keep latest 5 files in the respective folders.

```
for i in `ls -1rt | egrep 'nrld|mnrl'`
do
cd $i
mv *log /home/spsy/logs_bkp/$i
echo "files moved for &i"
cd ..
done
```

The below part is not working while I am adding the code to keep latest 5 files.

```
for i in `ls -1rt | egrep 'nrld|mnrl'`
do
cd $i
count_files=`ls -lrt | wc -l`
if [ $count_files -gt 5 ];
then
tomove=$(($count_files-5))
for part in `ls -1rt`
do
if [ $tomove -gt 0 ]
then
mv $part /home/spsy/logs_bkp/$i
tomove=$(($tomove-1))
echo "files moved for &i"
cd ..
fi
done
fi
done
```

Comment: Modified. It should be Latest 5 files

Comment: If you move everything to `/home/spsy/logs_bkp`, how do you deal with duplicate file names?

Comment: My files are generated everyday with unique timestamp. So there is no duplication of files in the same folders.

Comment: I am curious why you would not use `logrotate` to handle the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script is working. I have 4 folders named `ad1nrld,ad2nrld,icp1rmnrl,icp2rmnrl` in /var/log path. Script will keep latest 5files in the respective folders and rest will be moved to the respective folders of the `/home/spsy/logs_bkp` path.

This is the code.

```
cd /var/log
for i in `ls -1rt | egrep 'nrld|mnrl'`
do
cd $i
count_files=`ls -lrt | wc -l`
if [ $count_files -gt 6 ];
then
tomove=$(($count_files-6))
for part in `ls -1rt`
do
if [ $tomove -gt 0 ]
then
mv $part /home/spsy/logs_bkp/$i
tomove=$(($tomove-1))
fi
done
cd ..
fi
done
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694 (about quoting), and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985 (about `ls`). I'm also wondering why you use `ls` with `egrep` in your outer loop when you know the exact names of the directories that you want to loop over?

Comment: You should consider indenting your code blocks to improve readability. Also make sure your variables are always inside double quotes when you use them. Remember to put a `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file (first line) to show the system that you've written this script in `sh`.

Comment: This will break if any file name contains spaces. If this can be guaranteed not to happen then you're reasonably safe

Comment: Yes..It is guaranteed that file names are stored in a predefined manner and won't change in future. Also Shebang is added in the script as it will be executed from the crontab itself.

Answer (score 3):

`zsh` is generally available on Solaris unless you installed a stripped down version of it, so you should be able to do:

```
#! /usr/bin/zsh -
src=/var/log dst=/home/spsy/logs_bkp
dirs=(ad1nrld ad2nrld icp1rmnrl icp2rmnrl)

ret=0
for dir ($dirs) () {
  if (( $# > 5 )) mv -- $@[6,-1] $dst/$dir/ || ret=$?
} $src/$dir/*(N.om)
exit $ret
```

That uses the `om` glob qualifier to `o`rder the glob expansion (only *regular* files with the `.` qualifier) by `m`odification time (from youngest to oldest like `ls -t` does). Add the `D` qualifier if you also want to consider hidden files.

That glob expansion is passed to an anonymous function which moves the 6th to last files as long as there are more than 5 in the directory, doing it `for` each `$dir` in `$dirs`.

With ksh or other shells, without glob qualifiers the difficult part is to order the list of files by modification time and restrict to regular files only.

`ls -t` will sort by modification time, but you can't easily reconstruct the list of files from its output unless you can guarantee  file names won't contain newline characters. If you're in such a special case, you can do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
src=/var/log dst=/home/spsy/logs_bkp
dirs='ad1nrld
ad2nrld
icp1rmnrl
icp2rmnrl'

IFS='
' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable globbing so we can use split+glob to split.

ret=0
for dir in $dirs; do # split+glob to split $dirs
  set --
  for file in $(ls -t -- "$src/$dir/"); do # split+glob to split ls output
    [ -f "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ] && set -- "$@" "$src/$dir/$file"
  done
  if [ "$#" -gt 5 ]; then
    shift 5
    mv -- "$@" "$dst/$dir/" || ret="$?"
  fi
done
exit "$ret"
```

Answer (score 1):

Version, that does not rely on parsing `ls`, but uses `find` and `\0` as line terminator:

*(As you're using Solaris, and this uses `GNU` extensions, this might not be possible for you, but might be useful for others).*

```bsh
dirs=(ad1nrld ad2nrld icp1rmnrl icp2rmnrl)
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' \
      | sort -rnz \
      | tail -z -n+6 \
      | cut -z -f2- \
      | xargs -r0 mv --backup=numbered -t logs_bkp/
done
```

Comment: Note that `find -printf -maxdepth`, `sort/tail/cut -z`, `xargs -0`, `mv -t --backup` are all GNU extensions, and the OP mentioned using Solaris.

Comment: I had a feeling, that this would be an issue ... I'll leave a note, but this might be useful for others anyway

Comment: @pLumo Yes, GNU will not work in my Solaris versions (5.8).